# How to put a GitHub project on maven?

Tags: git, maven, github, maven-central

Plain and simple.

I have an open-source project on Github.com and people are asking me to add maven support.
Since I am not very familiar with maven I do not really know what to do.

How can I add maven support for my project? How can I upload my project to maven central?

Another question: Why would people want my project on maven since they can quite conveniently clone it on github?

Comment: They want it to be mavenized to get the dependency from Maven central which is very convenient for people. [To get into Maven Central just read the docs](http://central.sonatype.org/). I don't want to clone your project if i only want to use it. Can give the location of your project on github ? a link?

Comment: This is the project I am talking about: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General Guidelines on Mavenizing an Existing Eclipse project

> ```
> Create an empty Maven project of the same type as your original project (i.e. jar, war…) using the appropriate archetype.
> cd into the project directory that you just created and which now has a pom.xml file for your project.
> Run mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true in this directory.
> Import the Maven project into Eclipse
> Move the original project’s source code and resources into the new Maven project structure.
> Get all your classpath dependencies into your pom.xml
> ```

You could follow below guide for mavenizing your project :

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-java-web-project-to-maven-project/

People want it in Maven because :

http://www.kyleblaney.com/benefits-of-maven-over-ant/